# How to make jQuery FullCalendar's height fit its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to get rid of the scrollbars in the [calendar's](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) div in the agenda views (week and day) and only use browser's scrollbar if the calendar's content does not fit the browsers viewport.

So I believe I need to adjust the calendar's height to make its contents fit. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [`getView`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/getView/) method which returns current active View. And this `View` has its own method `setHeight`, so you can create a function like this:

```
function resizeCalendar(calendarView) {
    if(calendarView.name === 'agendaWeek' || calendarView.name === 'agendaDay') {
        // if height is too big for these views, then scrollbars will be hidden
        calendarView.setHeight(9999);
    }
}
```

And call it when view changed:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    viewDisplay: resizeCalendar,
    ...
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fJ37/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the thing is that I do not want to downsize the calendar. I want to make it larger so that it shows the whole day in the agenda view at once.

Comment: That solution only shows scrollbar if fullCalendar doesn't fit browser window. Check this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5fJ37/1/ (According to plugin source `setHeight` will not apply too big height for `Day` and `Week` views).

Comment: Cheers, I will try that first thing tomorrow. At least the fiddle seems to be working :>

Comment: It works. Would you mind editing your answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3):

From the version 2.1.0, you can use `height` or `contentHeight` options and set their value to `auto`.

The `height` option refers to entire calendar's height (including header).
The `contentHeight` option refers to calendar's content area height.

According to plugin's [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/), a value of `auto` means that the view's contents will assume a natural height and no scrollbars will be used.

Initialize the calendar as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    contentHeight: "auto",
    // .... other options here 
});
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/yj90oqzf/

More info here:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/contentHeight/